# Randomly sized rectangles on JavaScript canvas

Tags: javascript, random, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw randomly sized rectangles on my canvas. This is the code I have but it doesn't show anything when I run it.

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in your question.

Comment: Works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/95vajs9g/). Is your canvas wide/tall enough to show it? Does it have the id `myCanvas`?

Comment: I've fixed it thanks. If I wanted to draw more than one how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You could use a loop

Answer (score 2):

I think the sizing of your canvas is off and the rectangle is drawn off the screen.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', drawLine);

function drawLine() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = "100";
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.rect(10, 10, Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)), Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    context.stroke();
  }
```

```css
canvas {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue maybe that the origin of your rectangle is 910, 400. So your rectangle may be drawing but just off the visible bounds of the canvas.